# MS MySQL + get stats (as percentage) based of quiz answers vs correct answer

Tags: php, mysql, statistics, percentage

This attempt is a bit above my SQL/query skills, so I am seeking advice on how to go about getting it done.

**Summary:**

Have a table that logs a user's attempt at answering some quiz questions.

- current question
- provided answer
- correct answer

Here is the table layout:

```sql
create table quiz_answers(
    id int,
    submit_date datetime,
    session_id varchar(255),
    quiz_name varchar(255),
    question_num varchar(255),
    answer varchar(255),
    correct_answer varchar(255),
    user_ip varchar(255)
);

insert into quiz_answers(id, submit_date, session_id, quiz_name, question_num, answer, correct_answer, user_ip) values
(1, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer1', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(2, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer2', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(3, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'correct_answer', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(4, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer1', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(5, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer3', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(6, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer4', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(7, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer3', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(8, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'correct_answer', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(9, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'answer0', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(10, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer1', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(11, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer1', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(12, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer3', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(13, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer4', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(14, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer2', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(15, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'answer2', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(16, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question1', 'correct_answer', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx'),
(17, '2019-09-03 11:39:07', 'xxxxx', 'q1_xxx_quiz', 'q1_question0', 'correct_answer', 'correct_answer', 'xx.xx.xx.xxxx');

select * from quiz_answers;
```

```
|    | id | submit_date         | session_id | quiz_name   | question_num | answer         | correct_answer | user_ip       |
|----|----|---------------------|------------|-------------|--------------|----------------|----------------|---------------|
| 1  | 1  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer1        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 2  | 2  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer2        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 3  | 3  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | correct_answer | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 4  | 4  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer1        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 5  | 5  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer3        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 6  | 6  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer4        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 7  | 7  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer3        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 8  | 8  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | correct_answer | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 9  | 9  | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | answer0        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 10 | 10 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer1        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 11 | 11 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer1        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 12 | 12 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer3        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 13 | 13 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer4        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 14 | 14 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer2        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 15 | 15 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | answer2        | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 16 | 16 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question1 | correct_answer | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
| 17 | 17 | 03.09.2019 11:39:07 | xxxxx      | q1_xxx_quiz | q1_question0 | correct_answer | correct_answer | xx.xx.xx.xxxx |
```

[View on RexTester](https://rextester.com/NFVNW45787)

I am using PHP. I have the possible question answers provided for the user to select from (in an array or delimited string, perhaps to be used in the `IN()` portion of query?)

So for question: `q1_question0`

There are many 'submissions'

Possible answers: `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4` & `correct answer`

It is set up to always save the correct answer with every 'attempt' at answering the question  (thought it may be easier to get stats later this way?)..

I'm looking for a way to get a count/max or better yet a percentage of each answer vs correct answer.

ie:  something similar to-

- `answer1` - 25%
- `answer2` - 50%
- `answer3` - 10%
- `answer4` - 5%
- `correct answer` - 10%

or even:

- `answer1` - 4/10
- `answer2` - 2/10
- `answer3` - 1/10
- `answer4` - 1/10
- `correct answer` - 2/10

I'd prefer the % I think.. so I can use some sort of CSS/markup to visually create a progress bar or something..

This example is only for 1 question... that has 'x' number of possibly answer.. but each question differs in the amount of possibly answers there are.  (hence why I thought having the possibly answers in an array/delimited string.. to be used in the dynamic query creation)..  <- but don't let my lack of experience here set the tone in ANY way!  LOL

I'm not sure if this involves several sub-set queries as well?  (to get the 'stats' on each possible answer?) or where to even begin on this one?

Do I try to collect all entries with the same question name.. then somehow attempt to break it down by specific answers that are in the IN() clause and get a % from the total count of records by question name?

EDIT:

How to get a percentage of submitted answers vs correct answers?   A working table example was even provided, WITH DATA.

Getting percentage stats based on the answers submitted vs correct answer (for each possible available answer)

Comment: You might find [PHP MySql percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728900/php-mysql-percentage) and [Getting percentage of “Count(*)” to the number of all items in “GROUP BY”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061655/getting-percentage-of-count-to-the-number-of-all-items-in-group-by) helpful. Maybe even [Getting a percentage from MySql with a group by condition, and precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576370/getting-a-percentage-from-mysql-with-a-group-by-condition-and-precision).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ultimately used in the end.

I then used some PHP to do the math on things:

```
$statChecker_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = 'xx1')as answer1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = 'xx2') as answer2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = 'xx3') as answer3,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = 'xx4') as answer4,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = 'xx5') as answer5
 FROM image_quiz;";
```

Here is a dynamic example using PDO:

```
$statChecker_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL, ";
for($i=0; $i<$totalPossibleAnswers; $i++){
    if($i != ($totalPossibleAnswers - 1)){      
        $statChecker_sql .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = :answerValue$i) as answer$i, ";
    }else{
        $statChecker_sql .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_quiz WHERE answer = :answerValue$i) as answer$i "; //remove trailing comma (Im sure there is a better way)..lol!!!!!
    }   
}
$statChecker_sql .= " FROM image_quiz WHERE question_num = :targetQuestion";
$statChecker_stmt = $conn->prepare($statChecker_sql);

//dynamically add the potential values for parameterized query
for($i=0; $i<$totalPossibleAnswers; $i++){
    $statChecker_stmt->bindValue(':answerValue'.$i, $quiz['question'][0]['answer'][$i]);}
$statChecker_stmt->bindValue(':targetQuestion',$targetQuestion);

$statChecker_stmt->execute();
$statChecker_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statResults = $statChecker_stmt->fetch(); 
$statResultsCount = count($statResults); //current query index count

// submitted answer count * 100 \ total answers count
//output
echo '<br><br>Total Submitted Answers 1: ' . $statResults['TOTAL'] . '<br>';
echo 'Total Submitted Answers 2: ' . $statResultsCount . '<br>';
echo 'Detailed Answers breakdown: <br>';
for($z=1; $z<$statResultsCount; $z++){
    echo $z . ' - ' . $possibleAnswerArray[$z-1] . ': ' . $statResults['answer'.($z-1)] . ' / ' . $statResults['TOTAL'] . ' (' . round(($statResults['answer'.($z-1)] * 100) / $statResults['TOTAL']) . '%)' . '<br>';
}
```